# Encontrar chave e valor correspondente em arquivo de texto

Tags: php

Tenho um arquivo de texto:

```
0 GATO
1 CACHORRO
2 COELHO
3 RATO
```

E eu quero pegar o id e o valor correspondente, por exemplo: quando eu inserir 0 retornar "Gato" e assim por diante.

```
$text = file_get_contents('animals.txt');
$id = "1";
$id_str = strlen($id);
$pos = stristr($text, $id, true);
$pos_str = strlen($pos);
$pos_str = ($pos_str - $id_str);
$res = substr($pos, $id_str, $pos_str);
echo $res;
```

Dessa forma ele me Retorna:

> "Gato".

Mas se no ID eu colocar 2 ele retorna:

> "Gato 1 Cachorro"

Não sei se estou fazendo corretamente o uso dessas funções *PHP*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A flag em `$pos` deve estar em `false` para não incluir o que vem antes, aproveitando o teu exemplo:

```
<?php
$text = file_get_contents('animals.txt');
$id = "2";
$id_str = strlen($id);
$pos = stristr($text, $id, false);
$pos_str = strlen($pos);
$pos_str = ($pos_str - $id_str);
$res = substr($pos, $id_str, $pos_str);
echo explode("\n", $res)[0]; // excluir o que vem depois da quebra de linha
```

Não imprime nada se não for encontrado.

Mas acho que tens maneiras mais diretas e legíveis de o fazer, e não tão custosas. EX:

```
<?php
$lines = file('animals.txt');
$id = 2;
foreach($lines as $line) {
    $params = explode(' ', $line); // dividir cada linha por espaço, id - valor
    if($params[0] == $id && isset($params[1])) { // ver se é igual e cobrir a hipotese de poder haver linhas sem o valor (segundo elemento de $params)
        $ani = $params[1];
        break;
    }
}
if(isset($ani)) { // se tivermos encontrado o valor relativo ao id
    echo 'Foi encontrado o valor do id ' .$id. ' é: ' .$ani; // COELHO
}
else {
    echo 'Nenhum valor para o id ' .$id; // nao encontramos nenhum valor para aquele id
}
```

O que fiz aqui foi percorrer cada linha do array de todas as linhas, devolvido por `file('animals.txt');`, a cada linha vou dividir pelo espaço, fico com o array neste formato (ex da primeira volta do foreach): 
`$params = array(0 => 0, 1 => 'GATO');`, depois comparamos o `$id` que queremos com cada um na posição `0` deste array.

Se quiseres mesmo usar `file_get_contents`:

```
<?php
$content = file_get_contents('animals.txt');
$lines = explode("\n", $content); // acrescentar esta linha, dividir por quebra de linha para ficar com todas as linhas num array
$id = 2;
// ... O RESTO É IGUAL AO EXEMPLO ACIMA
```

Comment: Saquei, o `file_get_contents` lê o arquivo como string, enquanto o `file` lê ele como array, era isso que eu estava procurando mesmo! Obrigado Miguel!

Comment: Exacto @JacksonAntunes. `file()` devolve um `array`, em cada elemento é uma linha. De nada

Answer (score 1):

Ao invés de usar `file_get_contents()` você poderia usar também `fopen()`.

```
$arr = array();

$file = fopen('texto.txt', 'r');

while (!feof($file)) {
    $line = fgets($file);
    $arr[] = explode(' ', $line);
}

fclose($file);

var_dump($arr);
```

Saida:

```
array(4) {
[0] =>
 array(2) {
   [0] =>
   string(1) "0"
   [1] =>
   string(5) "GATO"
}
[1] =>
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  string(1) "1"
  [1] =>
  string(9) "CACHORRO"
}
[2] =>
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  string(1) "2"
  [1] =>
  string(7) "COELHO"
}
[3] =>
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  string(1) "3"
  [1] =>
  string(4) "RATO"
 }
}
```

Ou se quiser utilizar a chave dos `arrays` como o `ID` do animal:

```
while (!feof($file)) {
    $line = fgets($file);
    $itens = explode(' ', $line);
    $arr[$itens[0]] = $itens[1];
}
```

Saida:

```
array(4) {
[0] =>
  string(5) "GATO"
[1] =>
  string(9) "CACHORRO"
[2] =>
  string(7) "COELHO"
[3] =>
  string(4) "RATO"
}

echo $arr[0]; // GATO
```

Se a ideia for receber os valores por algum modo interativo, você pode colocar o recebimento dentro do `$arr[..numero aqui]` e pronto.

Comment: Interessante também seu exemplo, não conheço muito sobre a função `fopen` vou dar uma pesquisada depois pra saber mais! Obrigado!

Comment: resumidamente `fopen` = `open file` :)